# Make comment form, insert bbcode exactly where user wants

Tags: html, bbcode

I am working on my own comment form. I want use bbcode marker but in more advanced way. Now I add mark at the beginning and end of text from text area. I want add mark in that spot where user press button(e.q b as bold). 
Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: any variations with mark place. I searched how to get cursor position but do not really know how it should help me.